# What does a color deviation of 4.65 in Delta-E 2000 look like?

Tags: color-reproduction

So, my laptop's display has an 59% coverage of the sRGB, it looks something like this:

[image]
from [Notebookcheck.net](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Aspire-7-A715-7300HQ-GTX-1050-Laptop-Review.267346.0.html#toc-display)

The average color-deviation is 4.65, the maximum is 8.2

The thing is, I looked everywhere for examples of various Delta-E values, but couldn't find any. I now try looking here.

I'm not well-versed in the field of color-reproduction, so I'm not sure if I'm asking something stupid.

**What does a color-deviation of 4.65 and 8.2 look like?**

Comment: You need to ask this question on cognitive sciences, they deal with color science

Answer (score 3):

The definition formula of the color difference has evolved radically during the last 50 years. I guess the idea has been to find new versions which more closely present how people see colors. Organization CIE has published their formulas to be used for free. The evolution is described in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

CIE2000 version of their deltaE definition formula is so complex that it took nearly half a hour to read it through so carefully that I felt I understood the idea.

But there's color difference calculators in the web. With them you can input two colors in various color systems and see their deltaE. Both colors are also shown assuming the user has a properly calibrated sRGB screen (see NOTE1). Try for ex. this calculator:

http://colormine.org/delta-e-calculator/cie2000

You must input different color pairs to find colors that are apart of each other amount deltaE=4.65 Search another set of pairs that have difference 8.2

The searching methods 1) trial and error or 2) deep math analysis.

I guess you cannot find exactly fitting pairs because you can input colors only as integers. Here's an example:

[image]

The found 2 yellows have deltaE=about 4,59 and its quite noticeable.

**NOTE1** If you happen to have an uncalibrated screen there's no way to show the colors right nor to know how much they are OFF. Calibrated sRGB screen is one that can produce the whole sRGB color range and the screen itself or the combination your screen + your computer together have gone through a color measurement based calibration procedure. That needs color measurement instrument and calibration software. Common pure sight based calibration receipes are not valid for numerical accuracy.

Comment: Yeah well delta e tries to give a metric on how well people can distiguish colors as different. Anything above one is essentially (this is what it originally aimed to measure) a normal human can see the difference in less than 1 second of looking. Delra e of 8 is a lot

Comment: Anyway it might be prudent to tell people that the color swatches they see on their monitors do not reflect reality unless their monitor is 100% srgb. But the numeric values alone should make it clear enough.

Comment: OK, I inserted a disclaimer.

Comment: They (notebookcheck) did link an ICC profile. The problem is I saw a glossy screen (which usually has a wider gamut) on Screencountry that happens to be compatible with my laptop, but I doubt I can find an ICC profile for that.

Comment: @Mephistopheles ICC profiles provided by others are near useless. Each monitor in existence is in a individual state. So each monitor needs to be profiled separately. Also monitors change as they age...

Comment: @Mephistopheles get or borrow a calibrator. It finds your profile. At least for Windows there are several models available. Most advanced ones tell also how wide is the color range.